# Return JSON to GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get JSON to specific URLs in my application.

- I have generated controller:

  ```
  rails generate controller api
  ```

  - I have added 'test' method to my controller:

    ```
    def test
      respond_to do |format|
       message = { :last_sync => "hi!" }
       format.json { render :json => message }
    end
    ```
  - I have added route:

    ```
    # api section
    get 'api/test' => 'api#test'
    ```

When I trying to get URL:  .../api/test I get the error

> ActionController::UnknownFormat

on the line:

```
respond_to do | format |
```

Why and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Have you tried moving `message` out of the `respond_to` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use simple render without `respond_to` block:

```
def test
  message = { :last_sync => "hi!" }
  render :json => message
end
```

`respond_to` block needs if you want render many different formats. Like `html, json e.t.c` in one action.